# read cucumber result File within cucumber project

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

is there any way to read result File after the execution and generation of result file in through same project 
**i am using cucumber maven project**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/Feature", glue = { "stepDefinition" }, plugin = { "pretty",
        "json:target/sample.json" }, monochrome = true)
```

**mvn clean test**

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can read the file in the target directory.

```
SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().getParentPath()+"/sample.json"
```

Or you can extend the json reporter, to read the report before it's written